# Como inserir title a um Table charts da API do google Chart

Tags: javascript, google-charts

Na documentação do Google Chart existe a possibilidade de inserir títulos para um gráfico específico. Mas, para Table Chart não funciona. Alguém teria uma ideia de como passar para o componente a informação de exibição do title?

Abaixo segue um exemplo para gráficos:

```html
 var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                     'width':400,
                     'height':300};

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
```

Me parece que Table Visualization não suportam title!! Teria alguma forma de incluir sem ser direto no html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a [Documentação](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table), não tem essa opção para tabelas. O que você pode fazer é colocar o título acima da `div` da tabela:

```
   <h3>How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night</h3>
   <div id="table_div"></div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujktw6qz/)

Nesse [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples) tem outros exemplos de personalização das tabelas, usando `CSS`.